# Как пользоваться библиотекой FTDriver?

Tags: android, android-studio, usb, serial, uart

Пытаюсь реализовать [Android USB Serial](https://github.com/ksksue/FTDriver). Не могу открыть порт.

MainActivity:

```
FTDriver mSerial;
private static final String ACTION_USB_PERMISSION =
        "jp.ksksue.tutorial.USB_PERMISSION"

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mSerial = new FTDriver((UsbManager)getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE));
    PendingIntent permissionIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(
            ACTION_USB_PERMISSION), 0);
    mSerial.setPermissionIntent(permissionIntent);

    if(!mSerial.begin(FTDriver.BAUD9600)) {
      Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error! Cannot connect!!!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    .      .        .            . 

    String wbuf = "FTDriver Test.";
    mSerial.write(wbuf.getBytes());
```

[FTDriver вот](https://github.com/ksksue/FTDriver/blob/master/FTDriver/src/jp/ksksue/driver/serial/FTDriver.java)

> Выскакивает "Error! Cannot connect!!!"

Comment: где ее взять вообще?

Comment: https://github.com/ksksue/FTDriver

Comment: Кроме названия библиотеки должна быть указана и версия . смотрите [справку на jitpack.io](https://jitpack.io/#ksksue/FTDriver/v0.1)